# How to list all the symbols in use of a ruby/rails runtime/process

Tags: ruby

Just curious to know how to list all the symbols used in a running ruby process? eventually want to know the size taken by all those symbols, and is there any limit on that or how to keep it limited or whether one should worry about them when size is too much

Comment: you should take a look at http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Symbol.html, specifically the ``all_symbols`` method seems relevant

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To see them all:

```
Symbol.all_symbols
```

reference: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Symbol.html#method-c-all_symbols

I'm not sure how to find out how much memory they are using, or if there is a limit.  But, since they are never garbage collected, you SHOULD worry a bit about them.  In particular, you should never allow untrusted user input to be turned into a symbol - this can be used to run your application out of memory.

For an example of turning user input into symbols, imagine a rails action which turns a user-supplied string into a symbol:

> ```
> def some_action
>   my_sym = params[:p].to_sym
>   # ...
> end
> ```

Now someone can fill your ruby process space with as many symbols as they like by requesting millions of urls like

```
http://your_app/some_action?p=a
http://your_app/some_action?p=b
http://your_app/some_action?p=c
...
```

Possibly (depending on lots of things) killing your server when it runs out of memory.

Comment: very good point, any example of `never allow untrusted user input to be turned into a symbol`, what could cause allowing it. And I think am getting lazier now a days...

Comment: that also means to avoid to_sym method where inputs are not hardcoded or coming from users

Comment: one of my rails consoles says `Symbol.all_symbols.count #=> 48155`, is this normal?, any idea how may symbols could exist within any avg rails app

Comment: https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/2d3a6a0cb8df0360dd588a4d2fb260dd07cc9bcf - rails guys keenly avoid creating new symbols and using method_missing ... great

Comment: @Amol Pujari, I've added an example of how untrusted user input could be turned into a symbol.  Plain ruby irb loads with about 3k symbols; I checked a few of my rails apps and found their symbol count in the range of 25k-35k.  48k doesn't sound too bad!